# slurm can't execute srun

Tags: mpi, slurm

slurm cannot run

```
srun -n 1  /home/user/share/test/hello.o
```

is ok
rpi40000: 0 of 1

but

```
srun -n 2  /home/user/share/test/hello.o
```

is error.

srun: error: slurm_receive_msgs: Socket timed out on send/recv operation
srun: error: Task launch for StepId=53.0 failed on node rpi40001: Socket timed out on send/recv operation
srun: error: Application launch failed: Socket timed out on send/recv operation
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd-rpi40000: error: *** STEP 53.0 ON rpi40000 CANCELLED AT 2022-06-27T01:33:37 ***
srun: error: rpi40000: task 0: Killed

Comment: the issue could be related to node `rpi40001`. what if you `srun -w rpi40001 -n 1 /home/user/share/test/hello.o`? btw, is `hello.o` a MPI program?

Comment: Yes, hello.o is simple MPI program. MPI_Init and ... .

Comment: did you `srun -w rpi40001` ?